# Mounting a digital indicator on a plate

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, fasteners

I have a flat aluminium plate and I need to mount a digital indicator[1] on it.
The digital indicator doesn't seem to have any mounting holes itself so I
think I need to use a clamp to hold it.

I don't have much experience with industry standard parts in this area and I'd
rather not make something myself if I can buy it. So is there any standard
part or way I can mount this digital indicator on a flat aluminium plate? I can
drill holes in this plate no problem.

Any help is appreciated!

[1] https://shop.mitutoyo.eu/web/mitutoyo/en/mitutoyo/01.04.04A/Digital%20Indicator%20ID-H%2C%20CEE%20AC-Adapter/$catalogue/mitutoyoData/PR/543-563D/index.xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a 8mm hole drilled and reamed slightly undersize for a press fit 8mm dowel pin and use a 8mm/8mm swivel clamp which would let you set the angle and height as desired (photo from McMaster).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Clamping point.*

On the webpage you linked it appears that they hold the device on the 8 mm diameter rod sticking out the bottom. (Look at the press-mounted device.)

To  mount on an aluminium plate and have the back of the instrument in contact with the plate you just need a block of aluminium, steel, plastic, etc., and drill an 8 mm hole 11 mm from one edge. Slide the instrument in, line it up and screw the block to your aluminium plate.

You could slit one side of the block so that the fixing screw clamps the rod. Alternately add another block or clamp up near the 11 mm dimension to stop the instrument sliding out.